# geom_dotplot Gaps Between scale_x_discrete

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to make a histodot using geom_dotplot. For some reason, ggplot is giving me what appear to me are arbitrary breaks in my data along the x axis. My data has been binned `seq(0,22000000,500000)`, so I would like to see gaps in my data where they actually exist. However, I'm struggling to successfully list those `breaks()`. I wouldn't expect to see my first break until after $6,000,000 with a break until $10,000,000. Bonus points for teaching me why I can't use `labels=scales::dollar` on my scale_x_discrete.

[Here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/iwzn1t9yrkj931r/data2.csv?dl=0) is my data.

```
library(ggplot2)
data <- read.csv("data2.csv")

ggplot(data,aes(x=factor(constructioncost),fill=designstage)) + 
  geom_dotplot(binwidth=.8,method="histodot",dotsize=0.75,stackgroups=T) + 
  scale_x_discrete(breaks=seq(0,22000000,500000)) +
  ylim(0,30)
```

Thanks for any and all help and please, let me know if you have any questions!

[image]

Comment: I am not sure I understand your question correctly but I have you tried binwidth=.5

Comment: @MLavoie: Well, the easy fix that I made after your suggestion was `binwidth=1`, which gave me [this](https://i.gyazo.com/0a5801a0d4a80c55c47eb456852239ae.png). This is closer to what I wanted to see, but I am still wondering how to create "blanks" or "gaps" in the data so that there is nothing on the x-axis between $6M to $10M and anywhere else I don't have counts of designstage based on my binned data.

Comment: if you want to create gaps in your data, maybe 'constructioncost' should be used as numeric and maybe use scale_x_continuous instead.

Comment: @MLavoie: I tried that, but my plot just renders indefinitely and never is displayed. I always have to STOP and abort my R session. Can you confirm this method works on your computer?

Comment: did not work on mine as well; but I tried with the mtcars dataset and it was working

Comment: If you divide the costs by 100000 then using them as continuous works out and you get the desired spacing.  You would just need to label the breaks as you wanted or make it clear that the axis is cost/100000.

Comment: @aosmith: Thank you. I ended up just dividing by 1,000,000 to make it easier. Do you know the reason why `geom_dotplot()` doesn't play nice with large numbers? Also, if you want to submit as answer, I'd be happy to accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Treating the x axis as continuous instead of a factor will give you what you need.  However, you experienced the enormous range of your cost variable (0 to 21 million) was making ggplot2 choke when you try to treat is as continuous.

Because your values (other than 0) are all at least 500000, dividing the cost by 100000 will put things on a scale that ggplot2 can handle but also give you the variable spacing you want.

Note I had to play around with binwidth when I changed the scale of the data.

```
ggplot(data, aes(x = constructioncost/100000, fill = signsta)) + 
    geom_dotplot(binwidth = 3, method="histodot", stackgroups=T) + 
    scale_x_continuous(breaks=seq(0, 220, 5))  +
    ylim(0,30)
```

[image]

Then you can change the labels to reflect the whole dollar amounts if you'd like.  The number are so big you'll likely need to either add fewer or change the orientation (or both).

```
ggplot(data, aes(x = constructioncost/100000, fill = signsta)) + 
    geom_dotplot(binwidth = 3, method="histodot", stackgroups=T) + 
    scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(0, 220, 10), 
                       labels = scales::dollar(seq(0, 22000000, 1000000)))  +
    ylim(0,30) +
    theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, hjust = 1))
```

[image]